# Why can't I login to StackOverflow using my Technorati OpenID?

Tags: support, status-completed, openid, authentication

When I try to login to StackOverflow via my Technorati OpenID I get ""No OpenID endpoint found."  I checked and double-checked my URL and it appears to be correct.  Luckily I had a Google OpenID associated w/ my account as well.  Is anyone having any success w/ Technorati OpenID?

Comment: Did it work previously, but doesn't work today? Or is this the first time you tried with your Technorati OpenID?

Comment: It hasn't worked for the past week or so.  It definitely did work previously.

Comment: I have the same problem. it worked fine for some months and some days ago - no endpoint found. Nasty.

Comment: I am having the same problem with Technorati OpenID. Are we locked out of our SO accounts, or is there a way to recover the account?

Comment: BTW, this is the best non-info I've found so far, which isn't much: http://www.evilgeniuschronicles.org/wordpress/2009/10/16/technorati-shuts-down-openid/

Comment: This problem can be replicated on ServerFault

Comment: can be replicated for me

Comment: This is an issue with Technorati, and underscores why we recommend you keep an alternate OpenID provider associated with your account.  If you use Technorati and don't have an alternate openID, please email team@stackoverflow.com for further assistance.

Comment: @Joel I've sent an e-mail to the specified address. I'm itching to use my account again so I was wondering how much longer it was going to be before I got a response or this got resolved... Days, weeks, months? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technorati is no longer listed on the OpenId site: http://openid.net/get-an-openid/

There is an open question at Technorati's own support site with this question: http://getsatisfaction.com/technorati/topics/openid_support_has_disappeared_is_it_coming_back

The site supports openId login and you cannot login to it using Technorati as your openId provider.

I'm  unable to login to my StackOverflow (or any trilogy site) with my Technorati open id...